# mod-mono won't compile ascx file

Tags: c#, asp.net, linux, mono

I have the following useless error:

[image: error screencap]

I've reduced the ascx file to a basic form:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" %>
<div id="sidebar">
    <!-- More code would go here -->
</div>
```

The codebehind file is equally as empty:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace Random_Acts_of_Music
{
    public partial class Sidebar : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
    }
}
```

I'm setting this up on a new dev environment.  The production code already works in a similar environment.  I have no idea what to fix, since the exception gives me nothing useful, and I already KNOW the code works elsewhere.  Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Running Ubuntu Server 14.04.  Our production server is running 12.04, and can't be upgraded until we know this isn't going to break.

Many thanks!

Comment: have you tried Cleaning the Solution and rebuilding the solution..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE I copied the files from the production server to the new dev server because my existing dev environment is so screwed over.  There was no rebuild taking place before I copied the files over